# Execute bat file as a windows service

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a windows batch file which i want to execute as a service. I have found app like alwaysRun but i want to use windows in-build app for this purpose. Can anyone please suggest.

My Use Case is : - I have a batch file which will be executing after every 10 secs. So i have created a normal batch file which calls this bat file and sleeps for 10 secs. So i want to make this second bat file as a service. So that it is called once and when the windows reboots.

This file should be called as a service.

```
@echo off
:begin
CALL dummyfile.bat
timeout /t 1
goto begin
```

Please suggest.

Comment: This is impossible.

Comment: @KonstantinL No it is not impossible at all, but it is silly idea though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would not do that. You could run the first batch file from a scheduled task.

**OR**

If you want it to run at startup,

As an example, on Windows 8 you could

Create a VBS file that will completely hide your batch file.

**hideme.vbs**

```
Set MyScript    = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
MyScript.Run "C:\wherever\script\is\batch.cmd", 0, False
```

It can be launched as `cscript hideme.vbs`

Then open Start / Run and type `shell:startup` and press enter. Paste a shortcut of the VBS file here.

This will let VBS file call the second batch file in hidden mode each time the PC starts up.

**EDIT**
In order to kill it, you need to create another batchfile which you can run to find the cmd.exe that is running in the background.

In your original batch file, create a title at the very beginning after @echo off

```
@echo off
title LOOP
:begin
CALL dummyfile.bat
timeout /t 1
goto begin
```

Now in your new batchfile, let's call it `killLOOP.cmd` you add this:

```
taskkill /F /FI "WindowTitle eq  LOOP" /T
```

This will search for a process with Window title LOOP, then kill it. Just run it when you want to close it.
now in your

Comment: In the Scheduled task settings the script cannot be run before every 1 min.So i cannot try that as i need to run it after every 10 secs.

Comment: @IftekharKhan then use the method I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Set MyScript    = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
MyScript.Run "C:\Users\Documents\Python Scripts\Data_Extractor_Service.bat", 0, False

Comment: This is giving me an error that the system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: put the vbs file in the same directory as your batch file, and just do `Set MyScript = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") MyScript.Run "Data_Extractor_Service.bat", 0, False`

Comment: Okie.. now how can i stop this vb script from running as it is running in the background?

Comment: the vb script kicks off once and exits, you however have your batch file running in the background. So you would need to kill the cmd window (takslist)

Comment: okie...in that case i need to kill the task with the name "cmd.exe" .. But how will i know that it is the correct cmd.exe process and othe processes on the server would have also be executing cmd.exe ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer it worked. But can you please let me know the disadvantage of making the batch script as a windows service?

Comment: You need external tools to do it and it will become complicated.

Answer (score -1):

have you ever looked at the native Windows program called sc.exe ? It allows you to run a program as a service.

Here's some Microsoft documentation on it: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/251192/how-to-create-a-windows-service-by-using-sc-exe

> sc [Servername] Command Servicename [Optionname= Optionvalue...]

In particular, you could use the `Create` Command to create a new service:

> Create
>   Creates a service (adds it to the registry).

So the simplest syntax would be something like:

```
sc Create myservice binPath=C:\some\path\to\myservice.bat
```

Answer (score -1):

I executed batch file as a service, but it didn't work.

NSSM package resolved my problem. here are the steps to follow:

1- Download NSSM package

2- Add NSSM Directory path in Environment Variables Path

3- Execute command like:

nssm install Service_Name

3.1 After executing command mentioned in step 3, it will show a popup to provide
program file path. provide batch file path like "C:/Test/test.bat"

3.2 Click on install and now batch file will be executed as a window Service.